# Shiny - scatterD3 - legends not shown

Tags: r, shiny

I am testing scatterD3 and Shiny integration and found the following problem:

```
UI
...
box(width=12,title = "Gráficos", 
                           status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE,
                           collapsible = TRUE,
                           column(width=12,scatterD3Output("chart1"))
SERVER
....
output$chart1 <- renderScatterD3({    
    scatterD3(x = total_booklets$indice_K, 
               y = total_booklets$indice_Q, 
              col_var = total_booklets$Booklet,
              size_var= (round(total_booklets$Peso_Insert*100,2)) , 
              size_range = c(10,500), 
              lab = total_booklets$Booklet, 
              xlab = "indice K (aceleracion)", 
              ylab= "indice Q (residuo)", 
              col_lab="Booklet",
              size_lab = "Peso (%) Insert",
              point_opacity = 0.7,
              transitions = TRUE)
  })
```

The scatterplot shows but with NO labels for the variable Booklets nor legend for size_lab. What is strange, is that when I run in Rstudio the shiny app, it shows also teh scatter in the viewer with all the legends.

When I stop the shiny app, R prints a warning in the console:
Warning message:
In rm(list = as.character(handle), pos = .wsconns) :
  object '514026112' not found

If I do not run the scatterD3 plot the message is not shown.

Any idea???
Thanks in advance

Comment: silly question have you included library(scatterD3) in your ui.R and server.R files?

Comment: Yes. I have not included the full server, Ui and global files, but the libraries are loaded. In fact the chart is rendered BUT without the legends for color or size.

Comment: Package author here. Does the problem still persist with the latest scatterD3 version (0.5.1) ?

Comment: Strange. Works properly in other scatterplots. Can not reproduce exactly the error conditions. I will check all package versions and R version and let you know. Thanks!